# Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be the symmetric closures of $R_1$ and $R_2$, respectively. Prove that $S_1 \subseteq S_2$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

This is an exercise from Velleman's "How To Prove It".

> Suppose $R_1$ and $R_2$ are relations on $A$ and $R_1 \subseteq R_2$.
>
> - Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be the symmetric closures of $R_1$ and $R_2$, respectively. Prove that $S_1 \subseteq S_2$.
> - Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the transitive closures of $R_1$ and $R_2$, respectively. Prove that $T_1 \subseteq T_2$.

The symmetric closure $S$ of $R$ is the smallest set (under the subset partial order) such that $R \subseteq S$ and $S$ is symmetric. The definition for transitive closure is similar.

I am stuck on solving both of these problems.
For the first one, if I could somehow show that an arbitrary element of $S_1$ is contained in $R_1$, it would be easy to show that $S_1 \subseteq S_2$, since $R_1 \subseteq R_2$ and $R_2 \subseteq S_2$.

Any hints would help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contains = is a superset of.

The symmetric (resp. transitive) closure of $R$ is the least symmetric (transitive) relation containing $R$.

The symmetric (transitive) closure of $R_2$ contains $R_2$ and thus contains $R_1$; since the symmetric (transitive) closure of $R_1$ is the least symmetric (transitive) relation containing $R_1$, it must be contained by the closure of $R_2$ by definition of "least".

Edit: going in more detail. The case for "transitive" is analogous.

Consider a relation $R \subseteq A^2$. We define the symmetric closure of R to be $S = \{(x, y) \in A^2 : $ for every symmetric relation $S' \subseteq A^2$ such that $R \subseteq S'$, $(x, y) \in S'\}$.

Note that the symmetric closure of $R$ is symmetric and contains $R$.

Note also that whenever we have $S' \subseteq A^2$ satisfying the same properties (that is, whenever we have symmetric $S'$ such that $R \subseteq S'$), we will always have $S \subseteq S'$. Therefore, $S$ may be described as "the least symmetric relation containing $R$".

Back to the problem at hand. Note therefore that we have $R_2 \subseteq S_2$ and $S_2$ symmetric since it is given that $S_2$ is the symmetric closure of $R_2$. Therefore, since it is given that $R_1 \subseteq R_2$, we have $R_1 \subseteq S_2$. That is, $S_2$ is a symmetric relation containing $R_1$. But it is given that $S_1$ is the symmetric closure of $R_1$; therefore, we have $S_1 \subseteq S_2$.

Interestingly, it turns out that the symmetric closure can be given a simpler description. The symmetric closure of $R$ can be written as $R \cup \{(x, y) \in A^2: (y,x) \in R\}$. It can easily be shown that this definition is equivalent to the above.

Sadly, the transitive closure doesn't have a simpler description. It does, however, have a more "concrete" (or, to be precise, more predicative) definition. The transitive closure can also be defined as $\{(x, y) \in A^2 : $ there is some $i > 1$ and a sequence $x_1, ..., x_i$ such that $x = x_1$, $y = x_i$, and for all $j$ s.t. $1 \leq j < i$, $(x_j, x_{j + 1}) \in R\}$. This definition too is equivalent to the above (of transitive closure).

However, it's easiest to approach the problem using the "least relation" definition.

Comment: I think OP might be looking for a slightly more hands on answer, so if you could add a line about why this works! Also I feel like the word smallest instead of least makes sense. Least symmetric relation makes it sound like there are degrees of symmetry, whereas smallest makes it clear that you are talking about the relation and not the symmetry.

Answer (score 3):

Since $R_1 \subseteq R_2$ and $R_2 \subseteq S_2$ we have $R_1 \subseteq S_2$, but since $S_2$ is reflexive and $S_1$ is the smallest reflexive relation that contains $R_1$, it follows that $S_1 \subseteq S_2$. Similarly we can show that $T_1 \subseteq T_2$.

Comment: Really nice answer